# Way to count the number of people who have commented on a post?

Tags: comments

There doesn't seem to be an easy WP way to show the total number of different commenters, just total # of comments.

Is there a better than manually loop through all comments and counting the unique user ID's?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to count the number of **unique** *comment author emails* per post:

```
/**
 * Number of unique comment author emails per post:
 *
 * @see    http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/168606/26350
 * @param  int $pid
 * @return int
 */
function get_unique_commenters_by_post_id( $post_id )
{
   global $wpdb;
   $sql = "SELECT COUNT(1) as uc FROM ( 
              SELECT COUNT(1) as c FROM {$wpdb->comments} 
                  WHERE comment_post_ID = %d 
                  GROUP BY comment_author_email
           ) as t";
    return $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( $sql, $post_id ) );
}
```

**Usage example:**

```
echo get_unique_commenters_by_post_id( $post_id = 213 );
```

Comment: How would I echo that in the single post loop so it catches the current post id?

Comment: I wonder if you mean `echo get_unique_commenters_by_post_id( get_the_ID() );` @Pete

Comment: I found this worked... `<?php echo get_unique_commenters_by_post_id( $post_id = $post->ID ); ?>` in my loop.

Comment: @Pete glad to hear it worked for you.